# 404 (Not Found) for CSS and JS assets linked in the index.html of Angular 4 app

Tags: angular

[image: bootstrap assets linked in index.html]

[image: 404 error for the assets]

I get this error whenever I include any asset in index.html of my Angular 4 app from a folder. The asset locations are correct. How to solve this error and get access to all the assets?

Comment: Read the documentation of the CLI: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-include-bootstrap, https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-lib. The location can't possibly be correct: the base href is `/`, and the href of your stylesheet starts with `..`, so it tries going above the root.

Comment: I get the same error when including the theme file for Angular Material, although the official docs show the index.html approach. Do I have to do this there as well?

Comment: @JBNizet even if I link wrt base href, e.g., `./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js`, I still get the error

Comment: Read the documentation of the CLI: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-include-bootstrap, https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-lib

Comment: Change  base href=/ with base href= .